# Appended data does not seem to in markup when viewing source

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a website with some AJAX on it, basically the users clicks on a link, and some AJAX goes and fires a method that returns some HTML as show below, as the title says the data that is returned does not seem to be going into the HTML, is this why my accordions are not being made? It is strange becuase results are being returned because they out put onto my screen.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // hides the main_menu as soon as the DOM is ready
    // (a little sooner than page load)
    $('#main_menu').hide();
        // shows the slickbox on clicking the noted link  
        $('h3#show-menu a').click(function() {
                $('#main_menu').toggle('slow');
                    return false;
        });
//try and hide the left content when it is null
    $("#left-content:empty").hide();
    //style up the scroll bar
        $('#left-content').jScrollPane();

        //do some AJAX to call the method instead of the browser
        $("a.navlink").click(function (ev) {
            $(this).toggleClass("active");
            ev.preventDefault();
            var id = $(this).attr("id")
            if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
               $("."+id).remove();
            }
            else {  
            //$(this).toggleClass("active");
                  var url = $(this).attr("href");
                    $.ajax ({
                        url:  url,
                        type: "GET",
                        success : function (html) {
                            $("#accordion").append(html);
                            $('#accordion').accordion({
                                active: 0,
                                header:'h2'
                            });
                            //alert(accordion())
                        }
                    });
            }
        });
  });
```

As I am sure you can gather from the code, the returned HTML is appended to the `<div id="accordion>` and then it is 'turned' into an accordion, however this is not happening, all I get are the classes getting added to the div that would give accordion functionality but I get no real functionality.

I noticed that when I view source whether or not the AJAX has fired there is no content in `<div id="accordion>` even though I can see the returned data, how can I get the accordion to work?

=======What gets returned by the AJAX======

```
?php
if(isset($content)) {
//  var_dump($content);
    foreach($content as $row) {
        print "<h2 class='$row[category_name]'><a href='#'>$row[category_name]</a></h2>";
        print "<div class='$row[category_name]'>$row[content_title]</div>";
    }
}
?>
```

=========Where the AJAX html goes=========

```
    <div id="right-content">
    <div id="accordion"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The HTML source you see in the browser is not updated live, it is what the browser got when loading the page. To see the "live" HTML you will need firebug or a similar tool.

Comment: What do you mean by "It is strange becuase results are being returned because they out put onto my screen."? Are you seeing something happening on the page, or are you monitoring the requests using some tool?

Comment: That answers that question firebbug shows the correct HTML then is there any reason that my accodions are not working then?

Answer (score 2):

View source shows the source code of the file your machine downloaded, ie. the file BEFORE any AJAX changes.  No matter what you do in Javascript, nothing will ever change in view source (unless of course you go to a new page).

If you want to see how the current DOM looks for your page, you need to use a tool like Firebug or the IE Developer toolbar.

Comment: The FF web developer toolbar gives a 'View Live Source' option, which is a view-source-style representation of the DOM at that time. Sometimes useful, but nowhere as cool as Firebug.

Comment: +1 you can also --> Select the field you think should change, right click and select "View Selection Source"

Comment: "Sometimes useful, but nowhere as cool as Firebug" I think that sums up the web developer toolbar in general ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need Firebug from Firefox but firebug is a fantastic tool.. Select the field you think should change, right click and select "View Selection Source" (Firefox only).